# What is an efficient way to scale a int16 numpy array to a int8 numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, casting

Im trying to find an efficient way to scale 2 byte (-32K -> +32K) numpy int arrays to 8 bit (0 -> 255) using a specific scaling function.
The very inefficient method that works is (where minVal and maxVal are the min and Max values in the original 2 byte numpy array, and paddingVal in the original will be set to 0):

```
...

pixel_array = np.zeros( length, dtype=np.int16)
byte_array = np.zeros( length, dtype=np.uint8)

....

i = 0
for val in np.nditer(pixel_array):
    value = 0.0
    if val == paddingVal:
        byte_array[i] = 0
    else:
        value = 255.0 * ( val - minVal ) / (maxVal - minVal - 1.0)    
        byte_array[i] = (round(value))
    i += 1
```

I cant figure out how to avoid the loop and still do the if... and apply the scaling function.

thx

Comment: Just FYI: There's absolutely no need for the loop.  If you're not tightly memory constrained, just do `byte_array = (255.0 * (pixel_array - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal - 1.0)).astype(np.uint8)`.  You can set the "padding" values afterwards using `byte_array[pixel_array == paddingVal] = 0`.  It's not memory-efficient, but it will be much faster than what you're currently doing.

Comment: well that is certainly faster. Lovely how compact python can make it.

Comment: Just so you're fore-warned, the version I posted in my comment implicitly takes the floor of the values instead of rounding.  If you're fine with that, it's a bit faster than calling `numpy.round`, but it's not the same as your original code (@jorgeca's answer should give identical results to your original solution, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mask to benefit from numpy's vectorization (implicit loops), which will be much faster:

```
mask = pixel_array == paddingVal
byte_array[mask] = 0
byte_array[~mask] = np.round(255.0 * (pixel_array[~mask] - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal - 1.0))
```

It could also be done like this, which is cleaner because you avoid having to create `byte_array` beforehand:

```
byte_array = np.round(255.0 * (pixel_array - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal - 1.0)).astype(np.uint8)
byte_array[pixel_array == paddingVal] = 0
```

Edit: as Joe Kington points in a comment to the question, this trades of memory for speed.

Comment: That fails with an error, I tried something like before and get: byte_array[~mask] = round(255.0 * (pixel_array[~mask] - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal - 1.0))        
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Sorry, `round` is a python built in that only works for scalars. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
byte_array[i] = (((val << 16) >> 8) & 0xFF0000) >> 16
```

It assumes val is 32 bit integer between 0 and 65535

Comment: val in this case is a negative signed 16 bit int, so the above wont solve the problem. In any case, the performance isn't radically different from the original. Somehow, have to get rid of the explicit loop, I think.

Comment: @thefog you can convert a 32 bit integer that is between `-32768` and `32767` to a 32 bit integer that will be between `0` and `65535` with `(int + 0x10000) & 0xFFFEFFFF`. This would mean that after scaling `-1` (because it's full on bits in 2's complement) becomes `255` and so on.

Comment: @thefog Well it avoids floating point operations, multiplication and a call to round. I guess the code doesn't run too close to hardware if it performs the same :P